# Is it correct way having status or Summary columns in parent table or should choose another precedure?

Tags: sql, database-design, query-optimization, database-trigger, denormalization

My Parent Table is "Jobs" table, and there is child table that records Job's actions named "JobActions" as below:

Jobs (**JobId**, JobType, CurrentStage, AssignedTo)

JobActions (**JobActionId**, *JobId*, CreateDate, ActionType, FromUserId, ToUserId, Message, Detail)

in my grid in web page I list grid columns as below:

JobId, CreateDate, CurrentStage, AssignedTo, LastActionType, LastActionDate,...

In grid for calculating below columns I use joins to child table (very slow when there is many users and many data)

CreateDate ==> First(or min) JobActions' CreateDate,

LastActionType ==> Last JobActions' ActionType,

LastActionDate ==> Last(or Max) JobActions' CreateDate

I have about five columns like this that needs many join to JobActions or Another tables, So I Decided to change Job table like below:

Jobs (JobId, JobType, CurrentStage, AssignedTo, CreateDate, LastActionType, LastActionDate)

the last three columns always updated whenever any jobaction added to JobActions.

- Question 1: Is this a correct version, (am I denormalized my tables?)
- Question 2: Should I use trigger for this type of jobs or should update from inside my code?
- Question 3: Is this best practice? is there any better solution for this type of problems.

Comment: You have three questions.  That seems too broad for a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff are you saying I need to duplicate this thread for asking any of the above questions? becasue they all related.

Comment: . . I am saying that your question is quite broad and opinion-based.  Review the guidelines for asking questions and try to ask a more directed question.

Comment: There is no way we can help since we do not have the business logic.  There is no fundamental problem with what you did with your Job table.  As long as you respect the normalization forms 1 and 2 and 3 you will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 3: Is this best practice? is there any better solution for this type of problems.

"Best Practice" might be dependent on the environment. The recommendation would be to try and figure out why a VIEW is "slow". If you can't make it faster, then your solution(s) seem to be fine (after considering the other Business Requirements).

> Question 1: Is this a correct version, (am I denormalized my tables?)

In your original design, the JobActions table would be a **Slowly Changing Dimension (SCD)** Type 2 type of data.

In your other design, the additional columns (in the Jobs table) would be akin to SCD Type 4 type of data.

Your model looks fine (to me).

> Question 2: Should I use trigger for this type of jobs or should
>   update from inside my code?

Let's start with "should the update be placed inside your Application Code"? IMO - no. All applications should follow the same process when working with the same set of data. The only way to ensure that is to have the update logic within the database.

Should it be in a trigger? This answer may be highly opinionated.

On one hand, it could be easy to implement the required update logic in the trigger. On the other hand, implementing the delete logic might be difficult/impossible.

Thanks to [michael-kutz](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/145266/michael-kutz), for his completed click [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/264352/51034).